# How to integrate $ze^{-z}$ over the unit circle?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

How can I integrate $ze^{-z}$ over the unit circle?
I have tried expanding $z$ using $e^{i\theta}$ as well as $\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$. But I keep ending up with very long equations to calculate. I feel I am missing an important fact in calculating this but am not sure what?

Comment: do you know the residue theorem?

Comment: Or [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem)?

Comment: I am not completely familiar with Cauchys integral theorem, how would i use it generally and in my case?

Comment: It is not difficult to show that $\oint_{\|z\|=1}z^n\,dz = 0$, and since
$$ z e^{-z} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!} z^{n+1} $$
uniformly over any compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$, the outcome is clearly zero.

Answer (score 2):

Your best friend here is [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem), stating that the integral around a loop is zero as long as the function is analytic.
See the linked page.
In more generality, you can also apply [the residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), but it's not necessary here.

Comment: I am not completely familiar with Cauchys integral theorem, how would I use it both generally and in my case?

Comment: @Shanik Did you look at the linked page? As long as the function is analytic, the integral around any loop is zero.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed the link now, I will take a look at this now, thank you for the link. With regards to my question, as ze^-z, the integral of it is 0? So would it be sufficient enough to show that the function is analytic and then conclude that as it is, by Cauchys theorem, the integral is 0?

Comment: @Shanik Yes, the integral is zero because your function is analytic in the whole plane and you are integrating around a closed path.

Comment: Therefore just to clarify, by Cauchys theorem, as the function is entire the integral is 0

Comment: @Shanik Correct! All you need to check that the integration path closes, there are no singularities on or within it, and the function is analytic. In your case the function is entire (analytic on the whole plane), so the argument is very short and simple.